# How to upload a file and then check it and run some other commands using only ssh, cat, and diff in a single SSH session?

Tags: bash, ssh, cat, diff

The goal is to change some parameters on a lot of devices on connections that are kind of unreliable (wireless)--according to csv that has the format: IP,Parameter,Parameter

I would like to make a bash script that uploads a file, then checks the contents of it against the local copy, then run other commands using only bash, ssh, cat, and diff on the remote end. Only basic tools are available on the remote linux servers (Busybox), and there are thousands of them, so scaling is important. I would very much prefer to do all of this in a single SSH session, where authentication only has to happen one way, and one time. Pretend for the moment that security is not an issue. I am looking into how to scale rsa public key distribution to all of these, but for now, I want this to work with password authentication. Please don't make this into a banter about security practices. Perhaps there is a much easier way to accomplish the goal mentioned above. If so, please share. Thanks.

So the steps are:

1. Log into the remote box.
2. Copy the local file to the remote box in a specific directory.
3. Run diff, or some type of check for file copy errors.
4. If error, stop script, otherwise continue.
5. Run other commands on remote box.
6. Output the results of the commands to a local file.
7. Close the session.
8. Rinse and repeat.

Below is sort of pseudocode. But it gives you an idea of what I am trying to do. diff does not see the output of cataloging the local file, so it thinks they are not the same.

```
IFS=\,
while read IP PARAM1 PARAM2; do
    
cat /home/user/uploadscript.sh | sshpass -p $password ssh -v -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l uname 192.168.x.x 'cat > /tmp/script.sh && cat | diff -sb - /tmp/script.sh && IP="IP" && P1="$PARAM1" && P2="$PARAM2" && ./script.sh'
    
done < list_of_ipaddresses.txt >> log.txt
```

Comment: *Run diff, or some type of check for file copy errors.* -- not needed. SSH checks integrity of transferred messages. Only if you don't believe the filesystem below. You can use `ControlMaster` to make your code less awful.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure if I needed diff. Wow, ControlMaster! I think this is the answer! Googling how to use it now. Also I read about ssh-agent which looks useful for key auth. Thank you for your response! And, sorry to have you look at my awful code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, if I remember correctly, the answer was in the above comment about using ControlMaster. Thanks @Jakuje!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

```
{
  sha1sum /dev/fd/3 3< file-to-transfer &&
    cat file-to-transfer
} | ssh host '
  read sum &&
    cat > transferred-file &&
    echo "$sum" | sha1sum --quiet -c 3< transferred-file || exit
  cmd-that-expect-a-properly-transmitted-file'
```

(assuming the login shell of the target user on `host` is Bourne-like).

Note that `ssh` guarantees integrity of transfer, but the checksum verification would still cover for an aborted transfer and possibly a defective storage device on the destination (though the data would likely be cached). If it weren't for the latter, checking the size would be enough.

Comment: Can you explain the significance of the use of fd 3 here? It seems to be a red herring for me?

Comment: @StevenLu, that's an arbitrary fd to open the file on. Then, we get a `<sum> /dev/fd/3` on output of the local sha1sum, which can be used asis for the remote sha1sum in check mode.

Comment: You're saying that the file descriptor 3 is used in both local and remote environments so that the `<sum> /dev/fd/3` literal string content is identical as output by `sha1sum` on both ends, right? But, why fd 3 instead of stdin (`-`)? I assume because of some quirk, very curious what that is. At first I thought the fd 3 content was supposed to somehow get transferred over ssh into the other environment, which made no sense at all, but I don't think that's what this is.

Comment: Along these lines -- what if we had TWO files we wanted to send over. I don't even need the hash check. With two files we couldn't assume that the first item is only one line long... I found sending a file over ssh at the front of the connection with this trick is really handy when dealing with a slow VPN to save connection handshake overhead. But when there's more than one file it seems like the options are slim.

Comment: stdin is where the remote `sha1sum -c` reads the checksum to check so you need the data on a different fd. To send several files, you can send a tar/pax stream

Comment: OK! Now that clicks. Since we need fd 3 on the remote end due to stdin being unavailable, and that's why it has to be fd 3 on the sending end as well (so the sha1sum output would say /dev/fd/3 so that it can match...). Thank you! This is the beauty and art of unix right here. Also thanks for the tar suggestion. Very obvious in hindsight.

Answer (score 0):

The only command you need is `scp`. Like any other command, `scp` returns the status code 0 to indicate success or nonzero to indicate an error. If `scp` returns 0, the file was uploaded successfully.

```
if scp …; then
  echo >&2 "The file was uploaded successfully."
else
  echo >&2 "There was an error uploading the file."
fi
```